# Is it safe to use herbicide without clear withholding period?

Tags: herbicide

This year I would like to get rid of weed around wire fence and I'm considering using herbicide.

As much as I can see all non-selective (glyphosate) herbicides available at local stores have no information about withholding period (after what period it would be safe to plant or consume fruit/vegetables).

Is it safe to use such herbicides and how long should I wait before planting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Monsanto page [says](http://www.roundup.ca/en/faq) that it depends on the strength of the product used.  For the product used on perennial weeds, wait 72 hours.  Glyphosate is a contact killer that is taken up by the leaves, and then taken down into the roots.  It's supposed to be safe anyway in that there are no mammalian metabolic pathways that can be affected by this chemical.

However, the [WHO](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/mar/21/roundup-cancer-who-glyphosate-) claims that glyphosate may be carcinogenic linking it to Non-Hodgkins lymphoma.

There are lots of non-chemical ways of dealing with weeds that you might want to also consider.

Comment: Is this withholding period of min. 72 hours same for all glyphosate based herbicides regardless of manufacturer/brand? Does herbicide concentration or way of application make difference (spraying or applying directly)?

Comment: They use the strongest concentration for perennial weeds.  For annual weeds you can use a shorter period before planting - 24 hours

Comment: Note that they put other ingredients in glyphosate fertilizers besides glyphosate. Graham, do you know if those ingredients differ in more than concentration from product to product? If they do, Monsanto's official answer could be pretty variable. (I say 'Monsanto's', because of course, not everyone agrees about what is safe with glyphosate, and how long to do what).

Comment: @Shule I was under the impression that the main thing else they added were surfactants to allow it to stick to leaves. And these have their own toxicities.  But each manufacturer has its own surfactant that they add to glyphosate so one should look at the documentation if available for the product being used.

Answer (score 2):

When I was in pesticide...school, grins, there was an instructor who laughingly said you could drink this stuff.  ha ha.

The chemistry of glyphosate changes the second it is sprayed on another surface.  It does not leach.  It is systemic, not contact.  It is transported through the phloem from the leaves to the roots.  This is where the damage is done, glyphosate ruins the roots.  It takes 3 weeks for complete kill.  It takes 3 weeks to be able to plant seeds in that soil.

When used correctly, glyphosate worked well.  Too bad now we have to EAT this glyphosate in our food. Corn and other plants have been genetically programmed to be part glyphosate. They can spray glyphosate on crops without hurting the crops.  Just the weeds.  Now in my opinion that is like going after a couple of bad guys running around in New York City...with a nuclear bomb.  Killing everything including the two dumb criminals.  Guess it makes more money for the agricultural company.

But using roundup or glyphosate properly once every 5 years?  Can be labor saving and judicious.  But not be part of our food...

The MSDS sheets, that I had to read every single time I used glyphosate said 3 weeks for planting new plants or seed. If you buy gmo corn, you get to EAT it.  A bit different, huh?

Comment: If you drink the stuff, you tend to die

Comment: Not a fact, Graham.  I would want to die because I was stupid enough to drink that crap!  But we drink and eat fluoride every day which is far far worse than glyphosate.  Go figure.

Comment: Near fatal outcome drinking 200 mls https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4047698/ whereas flouride in tap water won't do that to you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hjh6T4x8-Zs  huh.  Thought I had written a comment to attach this to?  This stuff is far worse than glyphosate.

Comment: And again, this was in the WSU Cooperative Extension Service SEMINAR I attended to gain accreditation points for my license.  I am sorry, we all guffawed!

Comment: I had to post this https://youtu.be/ovKw6YjqSfM regarding drinking this stuff.

Comment: @stormy 3 weeks seems more reasonable period than 72 hours Graham mentioned in his answer. Just would like to know if it is 3 weeks after application or 3 weeks after weed is officially 'dead'?

Comment: Stormy - Glyphosate is a contact herbicide in that it only affects plants that it touches, which is why drift is an issue with it. Once it touches and enters a plant, it inhibits the EPSP synthase enzyme, which plants require. This is what kills the plant.

Comment: The use of 'contact' is simply not defined, then.  You bet, the only way the glyphosate can reach the roots is via contact with the epidermis of a plant and being transported vigorously to the roots.  Doesn't kill the epidermis on contact.  It should be called an 'extended release' herbicide.  If glyphosate actually killed the leaf it contacted with it would just kill the leaf.  I've never seen mechanical herbicide damage via glyphosate.  It is systemic.  Unlike, undiluted bleach, flame throwers...the whole benefit to glyphosate is total kill, from the roots.

Comment: @FalseIdentity this window of time after use of glyphosate is three weeks.  Three weeks from spraying weeds to being able to safely sow seed or plant starts.  I sure hope I did not make everyone think this was drinkable...I am telling you this was part of our education as Pesticide Applicators.  Very sarcastic. Trying to demonstrate there are battles to pick and battles that need to be picked but left alone for now...glyphosate is no big deal.  We EAT glyphosate when we eat GMO corn and other vegetables.  We EAT glyphosate chemistry  because adding glyphosate in our food makes money for....?

Comment: @FalseIdentity  this could be the same guy I listened to.  Saying the same things.  Glyphosate is actually a very handy pesticide a very safe pesticide in the hands of those who know how to read a label (5X each time you use said pesticide).  We need to teach others more so they are able to chose their battles.  Why oh why did this one conversation never happen during the last 80 years with fluoride?  Now this is a very big deal.  No one questioned in all that time?  And herbicides kill plants.  Pesticides kill animals.  Miticides kill mites.  Fungicides kill...fungus (as a preventative)...

Comment: We humans are animals.  Herbicides are a lower category for survival of animals than Pesticides.  Pesticides are made to disrupt bodily functions of animals whether insect, fish or human.  Fluoride kills all animals.  Industrial waste.  Just trying to help put glyphosate in its place.  I have been a licensed commercial pesticide applicator for over 30 years.  I tutored others, I worked with the WSU Cooperative Extension Service...got my master gardener cert 3X.  Great organization!  Not to mention food preservation and composting and pruning.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what concentration you used? I often buy premade products that are used straight from purchase- in theory one shouldn't have to touch or make a batch without touching the chemicals used. However I find many containers or sprayers used in the their design leak everywhere or seep out on hot days!
This is what it says on my stuff I buy: safe to replant or cultivate within 7 to 10 days after use anytime between May and September. However! if one reads more, it then says the effectiveness of the product can take from 1 to 4 weeks for the stuff to do its job? so your guess is as good as mine? 
No conclusion is offered because industry doesn't like to rubber stamp themselves into an impossible legal situation- is it safe or not, one minute it is and then the next like stormy hints there are health issues- I should say no one I've come across in the industry has a definitive answer too, and I was quoting a direct piece of literature from the actual bottle of weedkiller I use at work. needless I was surprised by the bottle offered as advice? no wonder everyone is confused...

Comment: I don't see why is this posted as an answer. No conclusion is offered. The original question (that is about herbicides without witholding data) is not addressed at all. This should be a comment, IMHO.

Comment: I have upvoted a lot of your answers, but not this time. This doesn't provide an answer as to how many days should pass before planting again after applying glyphosate. Please, at least provide the name and the concentration of "your stuff" that requieres 7-10 days. Currently your answer is in the low quality review queue and I admit I was tempted to press "recommend deletion", but I guess you could use a chance to add those details before me or somebody else votes to delete. It's nothing personal, it happened to all of us at some point.